# UnsupportedOperationException is throwed when try to remove the SelectionKey from the iterator

Tags: java, scala, unsupportedoperation

The code from below shows a small chunk of code which tries to accept the incomming connections from clients (typical implementation with java NIO), but when I try to remove the SelectionKey from the Iterator, it throws that exception.

This code looks very similar with [Jenkov tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html) and this other one [Acceptor (line 270) SocketServer from Apache Kafka](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/network/SocketServer.scala).

```
  override def run(): Unit = {

    this.logger.info("Acceptor started.")

    super.run()

    this.serverSocketChannel.register(this.selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT)

    while (this.isRunning) {

      val readyKeys = this.selector.select(500)

      if (readyKeys > 0) {

        val selectedKeys = this.selector.keys()

        val selectionKeysIterator = selectedKeys.iterator()

        while (selectionKeysIterator.hasNext && this.isRunning) {

          val selectionKey = selectionKeysIterator.next()

          selectionKeysIterator.remove()

          if (!selectionKey.isAcceptable)
            throw new IllegalStateException("The SelectionKey is not on the valid state [Acceptable].")

          this.accept(selectionKey)
        }
      }
    }

    this.selector.close()
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected-key set is returned by selector.selectedKey (you have selector.keys which is the specified to be unmodifiable)